# Glass material becomes white (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I made some glasses for my character, and gave the lenses a glass material, which works fine, except for the fact that at some angles, when rendered, the lenses turn completely white. I don't think this is reflection, because it does not gradually turn white. One angle it's fine, and turn it ever so slightly and it goes completely white.

[image: One of the lenses turns completely white...]

I have no clue what could be causing this.

EDIT: I have posted the Blend file on the Blend Exchange so you guys can check it out!

Comment: It's probably because of environment which is solid grey and that's way you cant see any gradient. Try to add some lamps or HDRI map and it should look different. Or maybe you are in Ortographic view? It's hard to tell just from the screenshot.

Comment: @LukeD I changed to perspective view and added a lamp but the problem is still there...

Comment: Could be also normals, try to recalculate or invert them, or just strip the file from everything besides glasses and upload it to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know anything about your scene other than whatever you share in your post, we don't know how you set up the materials, lighting, environment or anything else.

Comment: You can post your file using [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and then others will be able to actually examine your file instead of just guess.

Comment: @Whitest if you upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ you need to paste the resulting link as part of your question. Otherwise there is no way to find which one is your file!

Comment: @cegaton It is taking forever to upload so I will post the link when it is done

Answer (score -1):

@EVERYONE I messed with the IOR slider on the glass material and now it doesn't happen anymore... I will still post the blend file in case but I think it's fixed!